# My variable is called before dialog box delete function

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui

Hello i have a delete confirmation dialog box and 2 variables one that store an href and one that stores a remove row call. The problem is that the remove table row it's called before i press the delete button and i don't know why. The href is working good. here is my js:

```
<script>

$(".cart_quantity_delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tablerow = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

     $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
    url: href,
    success: function(result) {
      tablerow
    }
});

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: May be you need to change like this:  var tablerow = $(this).closest('tr');  and call "remove" in the success callback:      success: function(result) {
      tablerow.remove();
    }

Comment: hehe you're right, i tought it won't call that remove if it's stored in a variable. Thnx, add it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(".cart_quantity_delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tablerowObj = $(this); 
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

     $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
    url: href,
    success: function(result) {
      tablerow(tablerowObj);
    }
});

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

});


function tablerow( obj ){
   obj.closest('tr').remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move "remove"  function call to the 'success" callback:

From here:

```
var tablerow = $(this).closest('tr');
```

and call "remove" in the success callback:

```
   success: function(result) { 
         tablerow.remove(); 
   }
```